# Ubuntu Server 20.10 - www server

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, php

I know that for most people this topic may be trivial, but not for me.
This is lamp server, I have the latest version of php and mysql. I found out today that I can't use `Canonical Livepatch Service`
My questions how often should I update this server? Once a month? Once a year? Should I only update apache php and mysql? What's the good practice?
And what tools to use?

```
sudo apt full-upgrade, apt-get upgrade, apt upgrade & apt-get upgrade, apt-get dist-upgrade and apt full-upgrade ?
```

Comment: If you have [unattended upgrades enabled](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticSecurityUpdates), you'll get security updates each day. Kernel and microcode updates will require a reboot, which you can schedule or do when appropriate.

Comment: Personally, I do updates that are not security updates on a weekly basis (`sudo apt dist-upgrade`).

Comment: @Artur Meinild then reebot or not?

Comment: Livepatch is a snap service. Do you have snap available?

Comment: @Kulfy yes `Livepatchd error: The platform Ubuntu 20.10 is not supported. exiting.`

Comment: Is it a homelab or public server? If it's not interrupting your service that it reboots sunday night, I would reboot there.

Comment: @Artur Meinild public company server.

Comment: @Mantykora7 Oh. Livepatch is an LTS service only.

Comment: For a server, you should not use non-LTS releases if not really necessary for whatever reason. However, unless there are specific security issues with the kernel, you don't need livepatch. "Normal" software like your apache/php/mysql will update with `apt upgrade`. No Livepatch needed.

Comment: I would also generally recommend that you stick to LTS releases for server - it generally makes better sense.

Comment: @pLumo I will wait for the LTS version to come out and update.

Comment: @pLumo `apt upgrade` then rebbot or not? Once a month is enough?

Comment: No, you cannot wait until next LTS to upgrade. It will come out in 04/2022, and 20.10 will be EOL in 07/2021.

Comment: @pLumo I reinstalled on LTS

Comment: @Artur Meinild   I reinstalled on LTS

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution from @pLumo and @Artur Meinild.

The only reasonable solution and the fastest was to reinstall it on the LTS and switch to `Canonical Livepatch Service`.